# Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse helios (IDE for Java EE developers) 64 bit latest version

and when I am trying to update it from `help>check for updates`

I am getting the error:

> ```
> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency
> ```

Why I am getting this error, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are getting this because there is a conflicting dependency somewhere. For example, if you have plugin A that depends on dependency.X-1.0.0 installed, and try to install plugin B that depends on dependency.X-1.1.0, there is a conflict. When you check for updates, Eclipse will check all plugins and features you have installed in the past. Try to update one thing at a time to identify which update has a conflicting dependency.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is solution for that?

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem..instead I get "This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0. or above.Current version is 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508.Please update ADT to the latest version."

Comment: If it's an ADT thing, try this (link removed, but question id is 24693731)

EDIT: Don't do this if you don't want to kill Eclipse forever. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554856/application-eclipse-cant-be-opened-10810

Answer (score 12):

Download bundles from here:

linux 64 bit vm: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip

linux 32 bit vm: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip

mac: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip

win32: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip

win64: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

Starting with ADT bundle 23.0.2, you should be able to update to future versions of ADT.

Answer (score 8):

I couldnt get things working in the 'normal' update screen, but when going to 'About eclipse platform' screen and push the 'installation details' button. I got another screen, where you can select an installed plugin and update it.... in there it worked.

In there I first selected the plugin that seemed to be causing the conflict, and update it. Then the other one conflicting with this one... (the conflict in my case was between the android sdk and my java development tools)

Don't ask me why and what's the difference.... this option might be of help to others...

Answer (score 3):

If running on Windows 7, these errors can often be resolved by running Eclipse as Administrator, then update. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339659

Answer (score 2):

I Could resolve it by checking already installed plugins at where it was giving me this error. I just uninstalled all the plugins which had conflicting dependency and try to install the updates. It worked well.!
[check the marked area in this linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaqBq.png)

Generally, why it should happen is that while **updating plugins lately**,they have evolved 2-3 updates and during which plugins have introduced some new functions that have to be installed and also are to be updated. This thing creates conflicts of dependency. **Eclipse tries to update which is not already existing/installed and it also tells install it first which creates conflicts.**

So, when you uninstall the plugins, now it installs the latest plugins rather then updating. it means you updating eclipse plugins manually(by uninstalling older and installing latest). This may happen if you have skipped 2-3 updates and now looking for latest update.

Comment: what gone eclipse or ADT?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Michel.iamit.  I tried all other options of updating the ADT and it did not work.  With Michel's solution, my environment did not work and it complained about the conflict.

So here is what I did and got it to work:

- First uninstall all ADP Plugins.
- Then check for updates and it will prompt you regarding the missing plugins.
- Select all, accept all licences and proceeed.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by downloading the latest ADT release from following urls

1. linux 64 bit vm:
   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip
2. linux 32 bit vm:
   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip
3. mac:
       http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip
4. win32:
   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip
5. win64:
   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

After opening eclipse IDE go to **Help** ->**Install New Software**->**Add**

Name = ADT plugin , 
location = [link](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) and select all **Developer Tools** . After installation completed please restart your ide and all the bugs get solved now.

Comment: These are not latest ADT builds anymore... http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by running eclipse as root, and then installing the updates from Help>Install New Software and adding the latest update version to the download list (http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4). Not sure if this is the best way, but it worked to go from Indigo (3.8) to Luna (4.4). I'm doing this on Ubuntu 14.04 x64