# Not able to install eclipse for Android:Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to install eclipse helios but while "Install new software..." its showing following errors and could not complete installation.

```
  Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759               (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202   (epp.package.jee 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Android Traceview 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759)
To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.jee 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.1.20100916-1202]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L)
To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T)
To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.1.M20100826-1330]
```

Comment: Are you using `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` ?

Comment: Maybe you should't just ask a question, but do research first. This ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472966/cannot-complete-the-install-because-of-a-conflicting-dependency) probably answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download `Eclipse (Standard Edition)` from this link:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-43/keplerr

and the `ADT (Android Development Tool)` will be installed smoothly.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of eclipse have a look at Android Studio (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) it might be more useful to you/easier to set-up.