# How to update android sdk to 22.6.2

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

This Android Sdk requires **Android Developer toolkit version 22.6.2** or above
Current version is **22.3.0.v.201310242005-887826**

> Please update adt to latest version

When do update fails with this:

```
   Your original request has been modified.

  "Android DDMS" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "Android Development Tools" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "Android Traceview" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "Android Hierarchy Viewer" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "Tracer for OpenGL ES" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "Android Native Development Tools" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
  Software currently installed: Robotium Recorder 1.5.39 (com.robotium.recorder.feature.group 1.5.39)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Android Development Toolkit 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: RobotiumRecorderPlugin 1.5.39 (RobotiumRecorderPlugin 1.5.39)
    To: package com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt [22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Robotium Recorder 1.5.39 (com.robotium.recorder.feature.group 1.5.39)
    To: RobotiumRecorderPlugin [1.5.39]
```

Please someone help 
[image]

Preferences error
[image]

Comment: try below solution and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Press this button, you will get your SDK manager, you will get screen like this,

[image]

Just check mark that update and click on Install package and follow instruction.

**Edit**

[image]

Or may be you or someone have deleted your SDK folder by mistaken, in this case you must have to download all the SDk's which is required. Or you can copy from some one else and paste it somewhere in your system and just browse the path. That is also one way, so you don't have download it otherwise download it

Comment: hi InncocentKiller when I update it from SDK manager it gives me - Location of android sdk has not been set in preferences

Comment: Then you can set it manually, just click browse and set the location where your SDK is installed.

Comment: Hi Innocentkiller can you check second img

Comment: Okay, first of all check where you have installed your SDK, if you have installed then default path is `C:\Users\usernameOfurPC\android-sdks`, check whether it is available in this path or not.

Comment: no its no there we refer sdk from eclipse folder naa

Comment: I am having very bad feeling something is messed up it is there in directory but doesn't show in browse for preferences :(

Comment: @hunter, check my edit, how it will look. try it something like that

Comment: its not there I mean everything was perfectly till today morning n now its :(

Comment: Then may be you or someone have deleted it bymistaken, in this case you must have to download all the SDk's which is required. Or you can copy from some one else and paste it somewhere in your system and just browse the path. That is also one way, so you don't have download it otherwise download it.

Answer (score 1):

Download latest **ADT** from here then install it, your problem will be solved.

[ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Comment: hi Chinmoy I have did the same it is returning the error there only

Comment: pls check i have attached image

Comment: Can you follow this please - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472966/cannot-complete-the-install-because-of-a-conflicting-dependency

Comment: So in the end what I am I suppose to do shall I download eclipse again and then download Android 4.4.2,4.3,4.2 all those again which takes one heck of time and again import the projects do we dont have a fast fix for it

Answer (score 0):

Goto Help -> About ADT -> Installation details -> uninstall the old adt

eclipse will ask to restart. "DO NOT RESTART" just close the dialog box without restarting and goto -> help -> install new software -> "now install you new adt from link or zip file"