# Application "Eclipse" can't be opened. -10810

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-sdk-tools

After updating SDK for android L Preview, i tried to update ADT to 23 from adt 22 but it said version conflict.so couldnot able to update the ADT then i uninstalled the ADT plugin via about eclipse, after restarting eclipse was not opening up, it show the alert as Application "Eclipse" can't be opened. -10810

[image]

Comment: solved the problem ?

Comment: I have the exact same problem for the exact reasons, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me when dealing with the latest Development Tools version 23 problem with Eclipse and the Android Development Tools as noted [in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23).

The easiest solution I had found when getting to this state was just to re-download the [ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) package for Android development once again and install over the previous build.  This will NOT keep all the plug-ins/workspace/projects that you had in a previous state, but will get you back into working condition.  All SVN repositories can re-connect however.

Answer (score 0):

Looks from your comments that, You've screwed up your Eclipse environment.

You are left with only 2 options

1. Try to restart the system and stat Eclipse again. See if this works. Check again for installing ADT Plugin. It may not work that way.
2. Reinstall your entire stuff from scratch. Much better option to have smooth environment for you to work