# eclipse helios: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

when i try to install plugin on eclipse helios it give me this

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (epp.package.java 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Common Eclipse Runtime 3.6.0.v20100503 (org.eclipse.equinox.common 3.6.0.v20100503)
    Common Eclipse Runtime 3.6.100.v20120522-1841 (org.eclipse.equinox.common 3.6.100.v20120522-1841)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Traceview 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578)
    To: org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (epp.package.java 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.java.feature.feature.group [1.3.2.20110301-1807]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Core Runtime 3.8.0.v20120912-155025 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.8.0.v20120912-155025)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.common [3.6.100,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EPP Java Package 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (org.eclipse.epp.package.java.feature.feature.group 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.common [3.6.0.v20100503]
```

any solution?

Comment: If you look in the notes for 23.0.2 in http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html, you will see "Eclipse Indigo (Version 3.7.2) or higher is required." It's time for you to update your Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed, you have to re download the adt plugin from here.

```
linux 64 bit vm: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip<br>
linux 32 bit vm: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip<br>
mac: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip<br>
win32: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip<br>
win64: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip<br>
```

please follow the following link for more details. 
[Android : Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583267/android-cannot-complete-the-install-because-of-a-conflicting-dependency)