# when eclipse is opened it prompts asking to upgrade adt bundle

Tags: eclipse-adt

When i open eclipse it gives me the message:
   Android sdk requires android development toolkit 23.0.0 or above. Current version is 
   22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206. Please update adt to the latest version.

And i also checked the updates but no solution. Please can anyone help me out for this.
   Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: Not sure if it will help, but might: [Error: This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.1 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524789/error-this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-22-6-1-or-abo?rq=1). The selected answer was: I have solved this issue yesterday.

Follow the steps : Help -> Install New Software -> Add -> (Give any name suppose NewUpdate) -> add this url : https://dl-ssl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 -> OK

Now it will list the available updates, which should ideally be adt 20.x.x

Select the list items Let it be installed. Eclipse will restart and Its done.

I hope this will helpful for you

Comment: In the list of available updates should i select all?

Comment: think so. No harm in trying anyway!

Comment: I am getting this error.Operation cannot be copleted.Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

Comment: have a look at this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583267/android-cannot-complete-the-install-because-of-a-conflicting-dependency

Comment: I dint get it exactly like should we add those sites by going to install new software->

Comment: i don't suppose doing a clean install is an option? i.e. completely installing eclipse and reinstalling it again?

Comment: This might help you

Go to

Help --> About Eclipse SDK --> Installation Details..

Now you will see all 22.0 version and then click Uninstall button at bottom

After uninstallation goto

Help --> Install New Software --> http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

then install all the things now it is ready

Comment: there is no option like about eclipse SDK..which one are you talking about?? I am new to this please explain me wider.

Comment: what options are available under the 'help' tab?

Comment: think it's About ADT?

Comment: There seems to be several possible solutions. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23

Comment: anything here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472966/cannot-complete-the-install-because-of-a-conflicting-dependency

Comment: Selected answer was: "You are getting this because there is a conflicting dependency somewhere. For example, if you have plugin A that depends on dependency.X-1.0.0 installed, and try to install plugin B that depends on dependency.X-1.1.0, there is a conflict. When you check for updates, Eclipse will check all plugins and features you have installed in the past. Try to update one thing at a time to identify which update has a conflicting dependency.

Hope this helps!"