# Error in update ADT in Eclipse and IBM Worklight Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, adt

After update Android SDK I found this error message in Eclipse:

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above. Current version is 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206. Please update ADT to the latest version.

In Stackoverflow are several very complete answer to this problem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583267/android-cannot-complete-the-install-because-of-a-conflicting-dependency/24583769#24583769).
But I'm Working with Eclipse Kepler because is a requirement of IBM Worklight Studio.

Have I to update ADT to the latest version? 
IBM Worklight still working afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to Worklight.

If you want to update ADT, update ADT.
Worklight will continue to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can update ADT , as explained in those post you mentioned in your question, Updating adt won't affect your eclipse kepler version